# Why does a custom curl HEAD request hang for weebly.com?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, request, libcurl

When I do

```
$h = get_headers('http://www.weebly.com');
```

It works just fine... The headers for that page are promptly returned.

But if I try to retrieve the headers via an explicit HEAD request using curl...

```
 $url = 'http://www.weebly.com';
  $request_headers = array(
    'Connection: close',
  );
  $user_agent = 'curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15';
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'HEAD',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $request_headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $user_agent,
  ));

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The request does not finish.

What's wrong with my CURL setup? This works for other websites for http://www.google.com but for some like weebly it ends up hanging.

Comment: What do you mean by "same HEAD requests"? The [doc](http://php.net/get_headers) states that _By default `get_headers` uses a GET request to fetch the headers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because libcurl will act as if a GET is used but you change the method only in the actual request to HEAD, and that screw things up since the HEAD response probably has a Content-Length: header but no response body.

The "proper" way to have libcurl do a HEAD and expect a HEAD response is to use [CURLOPT_NOBODY](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html) instead.

[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html) should only be used to change method keyword, not to change behavior.